# How to bring the dropdown suggestion before the overlay?

Tags: html, popup, overlay

I have created popup with an overlay. In the pop-up, I'm having one text field in which i am getting location from google API. But, the location suggestion is going behind the overlay. How to make it visible in front? Can anyone help in this? It looks like

Image of the Location suggestion:

[image]

My code is as follows.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body.no-scroll{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.overlay{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 100000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.overlay-image{
    position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("&utm_source=facebook") > -1) {
        $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
        $('.overlay').show();
    }
    $(document).on('click', 'body.no-scroll', function (e) {
        $('.overlay').hide();
        $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-image">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="city" id="txtPlaces">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=xxxxxxxx"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtPlaces'));
            google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.A;
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.F;
                var mesg = "Address: " + address;

            });
        });
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need to add or change to bring the location suggestions to be visible in front?

Comment: The `z-index` has to be greater than your overlay to show it on top of it.

Comment: May I know which z-index have to more than overlay?

Comment: Perfect, its working. I have added z-index value more for the div overlay-image.